# Spark doesn't use SGD as optimizer any more?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I used Spark 2.4 and previous versions, and spark mllib is using SGD for regression problems as optimizer, and there are `LinearRegressionWithSGD` and `LassoWithSGD`, which use SGD as the optimizer.

It looks to me that Spark is using `L-BFGS`, `Normal equation solver for weighted least squares` ,`Iteratively reweighted least squares (IRLS)` as optimizer now (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-advanced.html).

I would ask why Spark gave up SGD and what's the motivation for spark to move to optimizers mentioned above. Are there limitations with SGD?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This explanation is for Spark version 3.4.1, the latest version at the time of writing this post.

If you look at this [doc page](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/mllib-linear-methods.html#optimization), you see that SGD is actually still supported for linear methods (like those you mentioned) and is actually the one that most algorithms implement:

> Under the hood, linear methods use convex optimization methods to optimize the objective functions. spark.mllib uses two methods, SGD and L-BFGS, described in the optimization section. Currently, most algorithm APIs support Stochastic Gradient Descent (SGD), and a few support L-BFGS. Refer to this optimization section for guidelines on choosing between optimization methods.

You can indeed see in the source code that these are still supported for your examples: [`LinearRegressionWithSGD`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/6b1ff22dde1ead51cbf370be6e48a802daae58b6/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/regression/LinearRegression.scala#L77-L86) and [`LassoWithSGD`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/6b1ff22dde1ead51cbf370be6e48a802daae58b6/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/regression/Lasso.scala#L76-L85).

Now, even though these are still supported, I did find some hints as to why you could prefer to use L-BFGS over SGD.

From the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/mllib-optimization.html#choosing-an-optimization-method):

> Linear methods use optimization internally, and some linear methods in spark.mllib support both SGD and L-BFGS. Different optimization methods can have different convergence guarantees depending on the properties of the objective function, and we cannot cover the literature here. In general, when L-BFGS is available, we recommend using it instead of SGD since L-BFGS tends to converge faster (in fewer iterations).

And also [this commit](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/6843d637e72e5262d05cfa2b1935152743f2bd5a) contains some motivation for it. The relevant part of that commit message:

> The PR includes the tests which compare the result with SGD with/without regularization.
>
> We did a comparison between LBFGS and SGD, and often we saw 10x less
> steps in LBFGS while the cost of per step is the same (just computing
> the gradient).
>
> The following is the paper by Prof. Ng at Stanford comparing different
> optimizers including LBFGS and SGD. They use them in the context of
> deep learning, but worth as reference.
> [http://cs.stanford.edu/~jngiam/papers/LeNgiamCoatesLahiriProchnowNg2011.pdf](http://cs.stanford.edu/%7Ejngiam/papers/LeNgiamCoatesLahiriProchnowNg2011.pdf)

Of course, this is always dependent on your exact case but this might give more context to what you were originally wondering about.